# Show UVC windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, universal-volume-control

Good day all.

Can i show/hide UVC (Universal Volume Control) from my code?

Maybe any API, for example `Device.ShowUVC()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to Windows Phone Mango SDK, **you cannot ask the OS to show the volume control UI through code.**

You can have some action on this UI through [`Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio%28v=vs.92%29.aspx), when your app play sound in background (ie. set if the UI show play/pause/shuffle buttons via `EnabledPlayerControls` enumeration).

Comment: how I can use EnabledPlayerControls? The UVC seems has no shuffle function!!??